# How can I override or merge the default policies in Amazon MQ (RabbitMQ)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rabbitmq, amazon-mq

There is a default policy managed by AWS (ha-all-AWS-OWNED-DO-NOT-DELETE) that is assigned by default to any rabbitmq exchange due its priority (0) and wildcard .* .

I am trying to match another policy with my exchanges with the definition:

federation-upstream-set: all

Since I am trying to create a federation upstream but any policy gets overridden by the default amazon policy, all my policies are being ignored so federation upstreams are unable to run.

Anyone has managed to make a federation upstream work using Amazon MQ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure queues in Classic Mode or in Quorom Mode?
I think you cannot attach policies on quorum queues because they're not supported by Amazon MQ. These rule is applicable for cluster configuration.

Take a look there: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/latest/developer-guide/rabbitmq-broker-architecture-cluster.html